# My Django view says it only takes one argument and two is given but there is only one

Tags: python, django, django-views, web-frameworks

I am working on a django project and when I try to run this function it returns that there can only be one argument given, but there is only one argument given.

```
from django.http import HttpResponse, Http404
from django.template import Context
from django.template.loader import get_template
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

def main_page(request):
    template = get_template('main_page.html')
    variables = Context({
            'head_title':u'Bookmarks!',
            'page_title':u'Welcome to bookmarks!',
            'page_body': u'store and share the bookmarks',
            })
    output = template.render(variables)
    return HttpResponse(output)
```

Url pattern

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import patterns, include, url
from socialnetwork.bookmarks.views import *
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^user/(\w+)/$', main_page),

)
```

Traceback:

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/user/Colin/

Django Version: 1.3
Python Version: 2.7.1
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'socialnetwork.bookmarks']
Installed Middleware:
 ('django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in   get_response
  111.                             response = callback(request, *callback_args,     **callback_kwargs)

Exception Type: TypeError at /user/Colin/
Exception Value: main_page() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)
```

Comment: What's the URL pattern for the view? That's where it's going to get passed an extra argument

Comment: can you show us the traceback?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I suspect that your URL pattern captures some other variable. If you attach a URL pattern to a view and that URL pattern captures any values, you need to have that view set up to take an argument for each captured value *on top of* the request argument, which is always first. So, let's say you've got a pattern

```
(r'^mainpage(\d+)/$', myview)
```

`myview()` needs to be defined like so:

```
def myview(request, digit):
    # do something
```

Comment: +1 for psychic debugging: you posted this 27min before Ulmer posted his URL pattern.  And you correctly identified the problem.

Answer (score 1):

request is always the first argument of a view, on top of other arguments you may have passed. If you call the view passing it 1 argument:

```
def main_page(request, arg1):
  code ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably pass additional argument via url.